# Cshtml file getting frozen

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-mac

After a couple of times changing and saving a .cshtml file, the view starts to get frozen.

I recorded a video, you can check it right [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lGk3bJYev53W8WZpxzPmJKfkZWmJ0y-z/view).

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: @mason is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known bug in VS for Mac and it will be fixed in an upcoming release. You'll need to update to the latest version (I'm not sure when that will be released, but hopefully soon).

Sorry for the inconvenience!